# Unable to consume web services using c# but working on postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, postman, webrequest

I am trying to call webservice through httpwebrequest. Successfully added XML document and headers but still getting error **Internal Server Error 500** . Same xml doc copied from debugging mode is working fine on postman. My code is

```
public HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction",action);
        //webRequest.Headers.Add("ContentType","text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"");
         webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        //  "charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
    }
public string CallWebService()
    {
        try
        {
           
            var _url = "https://xxxxxxxxxx/siebel/app/eai/enu?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&WSSOAP=1";
            var _action = @"""document/http://yyyyyy/:CreateFollowup""";

            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
            
            ServicePointManager
                .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
            //InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);
            
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    listBox_Log.Items.Add("saving soapenvelope.");
                }));
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
            
            // begin async call to web request.
            IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
           
            // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
            // do something usefull here like update your UI.
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            
            // get the response from the completed web request.
            string soapResult = null;

            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    listBox_Log.Items.Add("fetching response");
                }));
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        listBox_Log.Items.Add("collecting response");
                    }));
                    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
                Console.Write(soapResult);
            }
            return soapResult;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
public XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
    {
       
        XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
        
        soapEnvelop.LoadXml(@"xml code");
        return soapEnvelop;
    }
```

I have also tried bypassing ssl certificate because webservice server ssl certificate expired or not trusted. Please help as i am stuck. I have also tried WSDL file but couln't succeed for that as well.

**Edit**
Here i am adding images how i have tried *webservice in postman*
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you show how you created the request using Postman then it'll be easier for us to compare and contrast

Comment: Also what precisely do you mean by "tried WSDL file", that's too vague a description for anyone to know if you did it correctly or not.

Comment: This is about the 1000 time I answering this question.The default headers in c# are not the same as other tools for http.So best way of solving issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare first request in Postman and c#.  Also check for 500 error version of TLS that is being used.Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security leaks.  Microsoft pushed a security update in June disabling TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers.  Clients have to make sure that either TLS 1.2 or 1.3 is being used.  When not specified the default version of operating system is used.

Comment: @ADyson i have added postman images for you. This is working here with same headers and xml body. And For WSDL file i added it using _add service reference -> add web reference_. Then used its function. But getting error **Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with an empty response**

Comment: @jdweng please could you more specific or clear because i am beginner in consuming webservices. This is my first time. Earlier i was getting error that your mentioned **The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.**. But then i added certificate bypass code from internet then it shows new error **Internal Server Error 500**. May be what you said is right but i didn't get it.

Comment: Adding to jdweng's answer, I find it more practical to grab the request from Fiddler and instead of using Postman, to paste it into Visual Studio Code, with the necessary adaptations and try to perform the request using the REST Client extension. A very nice advantage is that when sharing a problem with others, I can simply share the text of the request and the text of the response, instead of Postman screenshots. Besides, because VSCode works with text files, I get to store my working examples together with my code in Git, which is very convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

After very hard finding, somehow i got to know that if webservice run successfully on postman that it also provide code for that language (just below save button). So i used that code (Based on **RestClient**).
***My mistake was not using \r\n and proper spaces in xml doc**.* So xml was the issue.

```
//THis code used for ssl bypassing
ServicePointManager
                .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;


        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(webservice_url)
        {
            Timeout = -1
        };
        var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        request.AddHeader("SOAPAction", "action");
        request.AddParameter("text/xml", "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"url1" xmlns:hhm=\"url2">\r\n\t<soapenv:Header>\r\n\t\t<UsernameToken>username</UsernameToken>\r\n\t\t<PasswordText>password</PasswordText>\r\n\t\t<SessionType>None</SessionType>\r\n\t</soapenv:Header>\r\n   <soapenv:Body>\r\n      <hhm:CreateFollowup_Input>\r\n         <hhm:FollowupAction>testing</hhm:FollowupAction>\r\n         <hhm:CloseOutSubReason></hhm:CloseOutSubReason>\r\n         <hhm:FolloUpStatus>Open</hhm:FolloUpStatus>\r\n         <hhm:Object_spcId>1-3B39WBFE</hhm:Object_spcId>\r\n         <hhm:Model></hhm:Model>\r\n         <hhm:CloseReason></hhm:CloseReason>\r\n         <hhm:FollowUpDate>08/20/2020</hhm:FollowUpDate>\r\n         <hhm:ExpectedPurchaseDate></hhm:ExpectedPurchaseDate>\r\n         <hhm:FollowUpQuestions></hhm:FollowUpQuestions>\r\n         <hhm:FollowUpDone></hhm:FollowUpDone>\r\n         <hhm:DSEName>10086S20</hhm:DSEName>\r\n         <hhm:MakeBought></hhm:MakeBought>\r\n      </hhm:CreateFollowup_Input>\r\n   </soapenv:Body>\r\n</soapenv:Envelope>", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        RestSharp.IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        return response.Content.ToString();
```